# Can rsync --include match zero-or-one-character?

Tags: rsync

Can

```
rsync -a --include="*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]" --include="*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]" --include="*.[Jj][Ff][Ii][Ff]" --exclude="*" tmp/a/* tmp/b/
```

be simplified to something like

```
rsync -a --include="*.[Jj][PpFf][EIi]?[GgFf]" --exclude="*" tmp/a/* tmp/b/
```

to match .jpg .JFIF .jpeg as does:

```
ls tmp/a/*.{J,j}{P,p,F,f}{I,i,E,e,}{G,g,F,f} 2>/dev/null
```

I created an example test that works, but I'd like to combine the image matching  
 includes into one     --include without the danger of 
`--include="*.[Jj][Pp]*[Gg]"` which matches foo.jp.png (which I don't want to copy.)

`mkdir -p tmp/a; touch tmp/a/foo.jpeg; touch tmp/a/bar.jpg; rm tmp/b/*; rsync -a --include="*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]" --include="*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]" --include="*.[Jj][Ff][Ii][Ff]" --exclude="*" tmp/a/* tmp/b/ ; ls  -la tmp/b`

Comment: You really shouldn't try to combine two extensions in one. The way you're trying to achieve this, you'd also include files with extensions like jfig, jpig, jpif etc. - You can always try to include the case-insensitive patch to rsync to ease up your line. [See this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/257595/548248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using a different tool to find the list of files and then piping them into rsync. Eg:

```
find /tmp/a -iregex '.*\(jpe?g\|jfif\)' | 
rsync -nav --files-from=- / /tmp/b
```

The `-iregex` means ignoring case. The regex pattern has an implied `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. The default regex type is *emacs*, hence the need for backslashes.

(I've left a `-n` in the rsync to not copy anything). 
Beware, using `--files-from` implies `-R`, which means the full path, eg `tmp/a/t.jpg`, will be copied to the destination, which is also why I've used an absolute path in the find, and as the rsync *from* directory (`/`). This is just to simplify testing until you understand what starting directory you need to give for the find and the rsync.

For example, to drop the `tmp/a` prefix you could do `(cd /tmp/a; find . ... ) | rsync ... /tmp/a /tmp/b`. The find will output `t.jpg`, and rsync will find that file in `/tmp/a`, and create file `t.jpg` in `/tmp/b`.

Comment: Thank you. **find tmp/a -iregex '.*\(jpe?g\|jfif\)'|sed 's,^tmp/a/,,'|rsync -av --files-from=- ./tmp/a ./tmp/b** solved this for me directly from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like @meuh's answer.  This answer explains why [meuh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398475/139893) is the way to do *zero or one* matching for `rsync`

I don't believe the zero-or-one feature is available on the `rsync` command line, according to the `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES` on the `rsync` man page.

`rsync` appears to use an expanded version of the shell's command line *pattern matching* ("globbing"), which is different than *regular expression* matching.

The zero-or-one feature is available in *extended pattern matching* of some shells (the `extglob` option in `bash`) but I don't see any discussion of this or similar *extended pattern matching* features on the `rsync` man page.